# After recent update of MikTeX, ! Package totpages Error: Can't use both, lastpage and totpages

Tags: lastpage

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\usepackage[top=1.8cm,bottom=1.8cm,left=0.88cm,right=0.88cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%\usepackage[
%   type={CC},
%   modifier={by-nc-nd},
%   version={4.0}
%]{doclicense}
%%
% \usepackage{doclicense}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{qrcode}
%\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{multicol} % cover page multicol

\begin{document}


% \doclicenseImage

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It was working fine when I installed and updated up to 17th Sep 2020.
Not sure which package casued it, but after the most recent update, if I add (put it back)`\usepackage{doclicense}`, I got this error now.

Comment: well doclicense loads hyperxmp which loads totpages which claims to be not compatible with lastpage which you load. Ask the hyperxmp author is he really needs totpages,

Comment: interesting choice of terminal font

Comment: `totpages` claims to offer everything which `lastpage` offers, too, so why not switch from `lastpage` to `totpages`?

Comment: hmmmmmmm, disabling `lastpage` does not really produce the `lastpage`. I don't think `totpages` functions at all in that case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue here after a recent upgrade in Debian Bullseye.

Before:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\begin{document}
  This is page~\thepage{} of~\pageref{LastPage}.
\end{document}
```

Which gave the error:

```
! Package totpages Error: Can't use both, lastpage and totpages.

See the totpages package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.35 \begin{document}
```

I replaced the `lastpage` dependency with `totpages` and changed the corresponding `\pageref{LastPage}` to `\pageref{TotPages}`. After:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{totpages}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\begin{document}
  This is page~\thepage{} of~\pageref{TotPages}.
\end{document}
```

This also works with an unnumbered title page. The `totpages` package claims it's meant to be used for the actual total number of pages, not the last page's number for which the `lastpage` package is meant, but this way it can do that anyway and it resolves the dependency conflict.

Result:
[image: "This is page 1 of 1."]

Comment: Thanks!
Replacing 'lastpage' with 'totpages' got rid of this unclear error message.

Answer (score 3):

With a recent distribution, neither OP's MWE nor [Luc's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574756/6865) load totpages anymore. Therefore there is no longer a problem when loading lastpage. Additionally, the error message of totpages can be ignored (hit "enter"). There is no reason for the error message to be there.

Comment: I guess this is good news then.